# How do i compile a java program with -Xlint through textpad

Tags: java, textpad

I'm in my high school programming class and during our latest project I am unable to understand why it gives me this message in the window:

```
Note: W:\Programming\Chapter 4\GrainAnimation\GrainAnimation.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: W:\Programming\Chapter 4\GrainAnimation\GrainAnimation.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I'm using TextPad if that helps anyone. How do I get it to compile with `-Xlint` through TextPad?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using TextPad I assume you're calling **javac** yourself to compile your classes.

Just add the -Xlint:deprecation or -Xlint:unchecked param when calling **javac**

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked MyClass.java
```

Extra: if you want to see all Xlint warning use -Xlint or -Xlint:all